# JPA - Double relation and foreign key of non-primary key

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables

1. Employees
2. Tasks
   Employees table have One to Many relation with Task table.
   SQL given below.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
 employe_id uuid not null primary key,
 employe_name varchar not null,
 current_task varchar not null
);

CREATE TABLE TASKS (
 task_id uuid not null primary key,
 employe_id uuid not null,
 task_name not null
 
 foreign key (employe_id) references employees(employe_id)
);
```

We ever I insert new record in tasks table, or create new employee record.
I need to add `task_name` in tasks table to current_task.

Is there any JPA/Hibernate way to do this?

Comment: There is a comma missing after `task_name not null` . And a varchar inside it.